# standard Directus - populate field on Detail view from a related record

Tags: directus

I'm new to Directus. I have a field for "previous record ID." If a user populates that field, I would like to automatically populate certain fields with values from that related record.

Am I correct that I should use interfaces extension for this capability, or is there a simpler solution I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into [Flows](https://docs.directus.io/app/flows.html#flows) for automating this. You should be able to use an [Event Hook](https://docs.directus.io/app/flows.html#flows) to trigger the flow on CREATE/UPDATE, and then add operations (eg: [Conditions](https://docs.directus.io/app/flows/operations.html#condition), [Update Data](https://docs.directus.io/app/flows/operations.html#update-data), [Run Script](https://docs.directus.io/app/flows/operations.html#run-script)) to populate other fields on that item or others.

This would be ideal since it is a no-code way to achieve what you're looking for.